# xterm reports wrong escape sequences on raw input

Tags: ncurses, xterm, terminfo

I am currently trying to do raw input in Linux (e. g. the stuff I'd normally use ncurses or similar).

I already got so far as that every single keypress is directly reported to my application and is dumped as a sequence of hex codes.

If I press the 'a' key on my keyboard, I get this output:

```
 #  hex string
00 0x61 'a'
```

This is pretty straight-forward. 0x61 is the hex code for an ASCII 'a' which I can, in turn, print using `(char) 0x61` back to the console.

Now I'm trying to do basic line-editing. If I press the left arrow key for example using `xterm`, I get this output:

```
 #  hex string
00 0x1B '\x1b'
01 0x5B '['
02 0x44 'D'
```

[According to this website](https://mkssoftware.com/docs/man5/terminfo.5.asp), in the section "Keypad Handling",

> The codes sent by the left arrow [...] can be given as `kcub1`.

According to the termcap file, the sequence *should* be `x1b O D`:

```
 ~ infocmp xterm | grep kcub1
kcub1=\EOD
```

While this happens in both *xterm* and *termite*, it does not in the default tty or *urxvt*.

According to the [xterm faq](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html)

> escape sequences [...] were chosen as "PC-style" codes (like SCO "ansi"), i.e.,
>
> ```
> ESC [ H
> ESC [ F
> ```
>
> for normal mode, and
>
> ```
> ESC O H
> ESC O F
> ```
>
> for cursor application mode

I guess I have to either set xterm to "normal mode" or replace all O's in the termcap file with "["?

**What would be the idial way of reading arrow keys for supporting both xterm & non-xterm terminals?**

Then, there's also the `cub` capability:

```
cub=\E[%p1%dD
```

[On the same page](https://mkssoftware.com/docs/man5/terminfo.5.asp), there's also a section about "Parameterized Strings".
I guess that's what the `%p1%d` in the cub capability refers to?

`%p1` refers to "push first parm", `%d` refers to "print pop() as in printf".

**What does all this mean?** What gets pushed to where? I don't call pop() at any point, what does the second option mean?

Thanks for any help in advance.

EDIT: [Here is a small C program](https://github.com/snaptoken/kilo-src/blob/keypresses/kilo.c) that demonstrates what I'm talking about. If I compile this using `gcc kilo.c` and run it, pressing the left arrow key emits `27 91 ('[') 68 ('D')`. Note the left bracket instead of the expected `O`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminal descriptions' list of special keys are written with the assumption that an application has initialized the terminal for full-screen mode, using *application mode* for special keys rather than the initial *normal mode*.  Command-line applications generally do not do this (they could, of course: look for `smkx` and `rmkx`).

Further reading:

- [*My cursor keys do not work*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#cursor_appmode) in the ncurses FAQ
- [*Why can't I use the cursor keys in (whatever) shell?*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_arrows) in the xterm FAQ
- [*Special Keys*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Special-Keys) in the xterm manual.

Comment: So I have to send the smkx string to xterm to get back to application mode, right?